# Is it possible to process an arrayList using Scanner, PrintWriter

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, printwriter

I have a method that reads from a file and puts all the information into an ArrayList. After that it can be read in a certain format using a method. 
Now what I want know is: Is it possible to use Scanner and the PrintWriter class only, to copy the exact same output from the terminal to a new txt file? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes its possible to read from one file and write to other using Scanner and PrintWriter.

Comment: Well, unless you are changing the order of the items when you process/print them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use Scanner and the PrintWriter class only, to copy the exact same output from the terminal to a new txt file?

Yes. It is possible. You can either:

1) Read directly from the original file (with Scanner) and write to a new file (with PrintWriter) or

2) If you want the output of your program to be saved in a text file:

```
C:\> java myProgram > myFile.txt
```

If you store your entire file data into a data structure like ArrayList first, there is a tendency that if the text file is too large, you will have a problem storing everything into the ArrayList at one go.

Comment: I want step 2  but what does '>' resemble? because I am doing this in eclipse and not command  prompt

Comment: The 2nd approach does not requires any code from Java. It uses command line operator to direct your output. It does not matter which IDE you use. If you want to work through the "Java ways", you can use option 1.